# Multiple Inlines in Model Admin in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, inline-formset

I have some models as follows:

`models.py`

```
   from django.db import models
    
    SET_CHOICES = [
            ('A', 'Set A'),
            ('B', 'Set B'),
            ('C', 'Set C'),
            ('D', 'Set D')
        ]
    
    class Exam(models.Model):
        exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        sub_code =  models.CharField(max_length=10)
        sub_name = models.TextField()
        max_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.sub_code}: {self.sub_name}'
    
    class ExamSet(models.Model):
        which_exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        set_name = models.CharField(
            max_length=1,
            choices=SET_CHOICES,
            default='A',
        )
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.which_exam.sub_code}: {self.which_exam.sub_name} (Set {self.set_name})'
    
    class Question(models.Model):
        for_which_exam_set = models.ForeignKey(ExamSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
        question_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
        question_text = models.TextField()
        max_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.for_which_exam_set}: {self.question_text}'
    
    
    class Choices(models.Model):
        choice_text = models.TextField()
        is_correct = models.BooleanField()
        for_which_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models
from .models import Exam, ExamSet, Question, Choices

# Register your models here.
class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 0
    ordering = ("question_order",)
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':50})},
    }
    

class ChoicesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choices
    extra = 0
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':30})},
    }

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question_text', 'max_marks', )
    inlines = [
        ChoicesInline
    ]
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':3})},
    }
    
    
class ExamSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
    QuestionInline
    ]
    

admin.site.register(ExamSet, ExamSetAdmin)

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin )
admin.site.register(Exam)
```

And this gives the model inline something like the following:
[image]

But what I wanted is to have the choices as well for each question in the `ExamSet`. So,

## How to keep the choices also in the inline of questions and questions with the choices in the inline of examsets?

I also should be able to add questions with the choices.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: it doesn't support by Django, you have to use third party libraries

Comment: @minglyu Any such recommendations would be useful

Comment: https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin

Answer (score 4):

As per @minglyu's comments, I have found a solution using the django-nested-admin. In case, anyone in future looking for such features, I have added the admin.py here.

Please make sure that you have installed django-nested-admin with

```
pip install django-nested-admin
```

and then, add the app in installed app like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'nested_admin',
    ...
]
```

Then finallly, in the `admin.py`, I have changed the code as follows for my `Examset` admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models
from nested_admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline
from .models import Exam, ExamSet, Question, Choices

# Register your models here.

class ChoicesInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Choices
    extra = 0
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':50})},
    }

class QuestionInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 0
    inlines = [ChoicesInline]
    ordering = ("question_order",)
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':50})},
    }

class ExamSetAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
    QuestionInline
    ]
    

admin.site.register(ExamSet, ExamSetAdmin)
```

Thanks!